# How to rollback database for each e2e test using ktor, exposed, hikari and junit5?

Tags: kotlin, junit5, hikaricp, ktor

I'm currently trying to create an integration test for my Ktor backend application by following Testing guide in the [Ktor Documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html#environment), where the target server is set to connect the MySQL database using Docker. The application consists of multiple modules and `external` module has `repository` package and basically uses the Exposed　DAO, and Hikari to manage connection configurations as followings.

I could set the test server and run the integration tests successfully though, the problem I have now is some of the test cases which change some data in the specific table affect other test cases. That results in some time pass, some time failed in the CI.

It would be grateful if you can tell me how I can rollback data in each e2e test.

- e2e test case example:

```
class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    fun `e2e Test for the Example endpoints`() = testApplication {
        environment {
           config = ApplicationConfig(application_integration_test.conf)
        }
        val response = client.post("/path/example/test") {
             header("Authorization", "token")
             header(contentType, APPLICATION_JSON)
             setBody("body")
        }
        assertEquals(201, response.status)
        assertEquals("[]", response.bodyAsText())
        ...
```

Datasource configs in application_integration_test.conf are set like followings:

```
   database {
        driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test?useSSL=false"
        username = testuser
        password = password
        maximumPoolSize = 4
        isAutoCommit = false
        transactionIsolation = TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
        connectionTimeout = 60000
        maxLifetime = 20000000
        idleTimeout = 10000000
        leakDetectionThreshold = 8000
    }
```

The target backend application is run with following code:

```
@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
fun Application.testMain() {
    setupIntegrationTests(ConfigurationSetUpper)
    installAuthentication()
    install(RoleBasedAuthorization)
    install(CallLogging)

    routing {
        testRoute()
    }
}
```

```
@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
fun Application.setupIntegrationTests(configurationSetUpper: ConfigurationSetUpper) {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

    val env = Environment.getBy(environment.config.property("ktor.deployment.environment"))
    configurationSetUpper.setUp(environment.config)

    DatabaseFactory.init()
    installIntegrationTestKoin()
    ...
```

The `DatabaseFactory` is fundamentally copy/paste from the example:

```
object DatabaseFactory {

    fun init() {
        Database.connect(hikari())
    }

    fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {
        val config = HikariConfig()
        config.driverClassName = DatabaseConfig.driverClassName
        config.jdbcUrl = DatabaseConfig.jdbcUrl
        config.username = DatabaseConfig.userName
        config.password = DatabaseConfig.password
        config.maximumPoolSize = DatabaseConfig.maximumPoolSize
        config.isAutoCommit = DatabaseConfig.isAutoCommit
        config.transactionIsolation = DatabaseConfig.transactionIsolation
        DatabaseConfig.maxLifetime?.let {
            config.maxLifetime = it
        }
        DatabaseConfig.leakDetectionThreshold?.let {
            config.leakDetectionThreshold = it
        }
        config.validate()
        return HikariDataSource(config)
    }
```

I tried with `rollback()` function using `transaction` block in the test code though, of course it did work since the transaction has happened inside the backend application, not in the client side.

```
class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    fun `e2e Test for the Example endpoints`() = testApplication {
        environment {
           config = ApplicationConfig(application_integration_test.conf)
        }
        transaction {
            try {
                val response = client.post("/path/example/test") {
                     header("Authorization", "token")
                     header(contentType, APPLICATION_JSON)
                     setBody("body")
                }
                assertEquals(201, response.status)
                assertEquals("[]", response.bodyAsText())
            ...

            } finally {
                TransactionManager.current().rollback()
```

--- Additional info:
Table schema and dummy data are set by Flyway migration before the integration tests start.

Comment: You can truncate tables after each test using the `AfterEach` annotation if you use JUnit.

Comment: Thank you @AlekseiTirman for your comment, and this is my bad, I forgot mentioning that the table and data are set by Flyway migrations that run before the integration tests run, so I cannot truncate tables, I just want to rollback the data.